# Google TV Channel Provider

Tags: google-tv

I'm currently a windows media center user using the dvblink product to stream tv. I'm looking to switch to Google TV but would like the same guide/streaming integration.

Dvblink have an android app, but they also provide a Client API that can be implemented.
So the question is, is it possible to implement a new Channel Listing Provider in Google TV and upload to a box such as a Sony NSZ-GS7?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

While you can implement one, you will not be able to have it supersede the existing ChannelListingProvider - you can install it but it wont work the way you expect. Effectively you can add any provider you want to a Google TV but it will not be picked up or used by any of the system applications.

Comment: +1 just because you took time from your job working on Google TV to help someone :)

Comment: Ok good news and bad news. 

I think I found my answer via this youtube vid from Google IO 2012 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bNbKpUqkOso

Skipping ahead to about 43 mins, it seems I need to build and deploy a new DeviceController to integrate my (Virtual) Media Device. Hopefully this can just be a thin wrapper around the client API I want to implement. I assume then that the existing central ChannelListingProvider should just pick it up...

Unfortunately, though this seems like the right solution, I can't find anything related to DeviceControllers in the API or SDK.

Comment: We decided not to publish the api in the most recent release. We are evaluating the api for a future release.